# pandas series with multidimensional data

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas series with 3 indexes (0,1,2), each contains a 2-d array (such as an image). How can I slice across all indexes to get values at a pixel location of (x,y) in the 2-d array?

```
s = pd.Series({0 : [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], 1: [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]], 2 : [[1, 2, 3], [11, 12, 13]]})
```

I want to return an array `[5,8,12]` that each element is at `[1,1]`.

`s[0:2][x][y]` or `s[:,x,y]` don't work.

Is this a bad data structure? or is Pandas series not intended to store multi-dimensional data?

Comment: My suggestion is to use [Panels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel) for that problem

Comment: You can also check out xarray, which is intended for multidimensional data, but I've had some bad experiences with it.